# Failure to transfer org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.2.2

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pom.xml

I want to write an Excel file with apache-poi.

If I use the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works fine, but if I try to update to the newest version (5.2.2), I get the following error in my pom.xml:

> Failure to transfer org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.2.2 from was cached
> in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
> update interval  of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
> Original error: Could not transfer  artifact
> org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.2.2 from/to central Error code 500,
> Server Error

I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Are you connecting directly or Maven Central, or do you have a proxy or your own repository server? The error 500 suggests a server issue. I just tried to download this specific file from Maven Central, and it downloaded just fine. Either this was a transient error, and trying again should fix it for you  (you may want to try using `-U` in your Maven commandline), or you have an issue with your proxy/repository server. Alternatively, go to your local repository folder and delete the `org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml` directory to force a redownload.

Comment: Looks like its a problem with the repository server thank you